# JavaFX MediaPlayer: MP4 loop freeze, sound distorted, Windows 7

Tags: java, scala, javafx, media-player, freeze

We have a problem with JavaFX MediaPlayer for more than a month now. We read and tried all the similar problems here, nothing worked.
Simplest example: It's an info app with 2 videos from a folder played continualy in a loop. After some time (sometimes 2h, sometimes 2 days) 
videos start to slow down, duration is longer, occasional freeze, sound becomes distorted.

OS: win7 64b (Ultimate) SP1
Intel Celeron CPU N3150 @1.6GHz
8 GB Ram
java 1.8 and 1.10, 64b

Tried:
OS update, latest.
Drivers updates, other drivers.
JDK 64b, 1.8 latest updates, JDK 1.10 latest.
Changing code (adding dispose, closing, setting null, caching... every suggestion on stackoverflow)
Changing video encoders: MPEG-4, H.264 and H.264-HD, 1500/2000/4000/8000 kbps, 25fps
Changing resolutions: 1280x720, 
Sound: AAC, 1 and 2 channels, 48 & 44 kHz, 128kbps bit rate and others. Tried videos without audio.

Almost every possible combination of these video/sound encoders, bitrates, resolutions, framerates ...
We profiled for memory leaks: memory grows for some time and it stops growing. It's ok (we think).

Nothing we tried has worked. No errors, no exceptions on MediaView, Media, Player. No system events.

Confusing: we noticed that that in normal operations CPU is 20-30%, but, when videos start to freeze, it's lower, 5-15%.

Code (latest version):

```
import java.io.File
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, Props, Timers}
import akka.pattern._
import com.commercial.activity.MMDriver.ShowNextMedia
import javafx.event.EventHandler
import javafx.scene.media.{Media, MediaErrorEvent, MediaPlayer, MediaView}

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

object MMDriver {
  def props(rootFolder: File, allowedExtension: List[String],
            showMedia: (MMedia) => Unit): Props = Props(new MMDriver(rootFolder, allowedExtension, showMedia))

  case object Start
  case class MediaCreated(list: List[MMedia])
  case object ShowNextMedia
}

class MMDriver(rootFolder: File, allowedExtensions: List[String],
               showMedia: (MMedia) => Unit) extends Actor with ActorLogging with Timers {

  object TimerKey
  var started = false
  var medias = List[MMedia]()
  var index = 0

  override def receive: Receive = {

    case MMDriver.Start if (!started) =>
      started = true
      Future {
        loadMedia(rootFolder, allowedExtensions)
          .map { file =>
            val media = new Media(file.toURI.toURL.toString)
            val player = new MediaPlayer(media)
            //next video
            player.setOnEndOfMedia(new Runnable {
              override def run(): Unit = {
                self ! ShowNextMedia
              }
            })
            val mediaView = new MediaView(player)
            setErrorHandlers(player, media, mediaView)
            MMedia(file, media, player, mediaView)
          }
      }
        .map(media => MMDriver.MediaCreated(media.toList))
        .pipeTo(self)

    case MMDriver.MediaCreated(list) =>
      medias = list
      if (medias.nonEmpty) {
        self ! ShowNextMedia
      }

    case MMDriver.ShowNextMedia =>
      val media = medias(index)
      showMedia(media)
      index = index + 1
      index = index % medias.size

    case msg =>
      log.info("not processed message {}", msg)
  }

  private def loadMedia(folder: File, allowedExtensions: List[String]): Array[File] = {
    folder.listFiles()
      .filter { file =>
        allowedExtensions.exists(file.getName.endsWith(_))
      }
  }

  private def setErrorHandlers(player: MediaPlayer, media: Media, mediaView: MediaView): Unit = {
    player.setOnError(new Runnable {
      override def run(): Unit = {
        log.error(player.getError, "error in player")
      }
    })

    media.setOnError(new Runnable {
      override def run(): Unit = {
        log.error(media.getError, "error in media")
      }
    })

    mediaView.setOnError(new EventHandler[MediaErrorEvent] {
      override def handle(event: MediaErrorEvent): Unit = {
        log.error(event.getMediaError, "error in mediaView")
      }
    })
  }

}
```

Any suggestion what to try next - we are out of ideas?!

Comment: Have you considered "restarting" the `MediaPlayer` every once in a while? By restarting, I mean create a new `MediaPlayer` periodically.

Comment: Yes. We had one version where we would show a vid, then dispose() it, then for the new vid we would create new plyaer, and done that in a loop. Same happened.

Comment: Is there any other alternative implementation for media? Maybe to try some other approach - we lost much time with this. Testing is time consuming - you start the demo, it works ... and maybe tomorrow it crashes.